# Derivation of traffic flow equation

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm trying to derive the equation $\rho=qu$, where $\rho$ is density, $u$ is velocity, and $q$ is flow.

The approach I'm told to take:

Imagine standing on the side of the road at position $x$ and you count the number of cars that pass from time $t$ to $T$.

1. Express the number of cars counted in terms of $q$:

I got this.
 $\int_{t}^{T} q(x,\tau) d\tau$

2. Recognize that, at the instant $T$ , all of the cars that you just have counted (and only those)are occupying the stretch of the road to the right of you, between $x$ and wherever the very first car you counted (the one you counted at time t) is at at time $T$. Denote position of that “very first car” as a function of time by $b(t)$. Then the “stretch of the road” referred to above is between $x$ and $b(T)$. Use this observation to express the number of cars you have counted in terms of $\rho$. Do this.

This is the part that I am stuck on. I get that $\rho$ is density, which is $\frac{\text{number of cars}}{\text{unit time}}$. What I'm not understanding is where the $b(t)$ comes in. The hint I was given is:

> view $b(t)$ as a position function. that is, $x = b(t)$.
>
> $u(x,t)$ is the Velocity field and $u(b(t),t)$ would be the velocity of a single car.
>
> ?question to you? what does $\frac{db}{dt}$ represent?

I guess I'm just not understanding entirely how $b(t)$ folds into this problem.Hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_diagram_of_traffic_flow) help?